# Cron running job multiple times

Tags: cron

Hello I have a cron job that I have setup, everything was working just fine until a couple of minutes ago when my cron job scheduled to only run every five hours started to run several processes every single minute.

My cron job is specified as:

```
* */5 * * * php -f [path] >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a star (*) matches every value for the particular field. The date and time fields are at the beginning of an entry and consist of: MIN HOUR DAY_OF_MONTH MONTH DAY_OF_WEEK

So, when you write "* */5 * * *" it means every minute, every 5 hours, every day... The problem lies in the "every minute" selection. I guess you want to change it to a single value between 0..59. For more information do, "man 5 crontab".